# Getting java.lang.IllegalStateException when I try to use getSystemService in library project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-library

I'm trying to build a library which pops up `persistent notification` on the system tray whenever included in the application project. I have made a normal application and tested it on device which is running perfectly fine. Now, I have converted that project into library and referencing that library to android project.

Here is my `MainActivity` which is nameed as `SearchBar` of the library project:

```
public class SearchBar extends Activity {

NotificationManager nm;
public static String PACKAGE_NAME;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search_bar);

    PACKAGE_NAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
}

public void searchBar() {

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_stat_notify,
            "STest", System.currentTimeMillis());

    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(PACKAGE_NAME,
            R.layout.persistent_notification_layout);

    notification.contentView = contentView;

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
    notificationIntent.setClassName("com.example.searchbar",
            "com.example.searchbar.SearchAutoSuggest");

    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(SearchBar.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 2,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;

    nm.notify(AppSingleton.NOTIFICATION_ID_ALWAYS, notification);
}

}
```

And, I'm calling this library into my `testProject's` `MainActivity` like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

SearchBar notification;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    notification = new SearchBar();

    notification.searchBar();

}
}
```

Now, when I run my `testProject` I get error stating as:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:4463)
at com.example.searchbar.SearchBar.searchBar(SearchBar.java:43)
at com.example.libtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
```

On:

```
nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(SearchBar.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

I tried/searched several stuff, but non of them is helping me to resolve the problem.
What am I doing wrong? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities
>   before onCreate()

because you are extending Activity in `SearchBar` class but not registering in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

so create `SearchBar` class as normal java class without extending Activity and pass MainActivity context to SearchBar class using class constructor or as method parameters as:

```
public class SearchBar {

NotificationManager nm;
public static String PACKAGE_NAME;
Context context;
 public  SearchBar(Context context) {
    this.context=context;
    PACKAGE_NAME = context.getPackageName();
}
....
```

Comment: Thanks much for this. Can you tell me one more thing. I have to pass `Intent` when user taps on the notification. The `activity` class is inside my library, for this I just have to add activity in my `testProject's` manifest file. That' it?

Accepting your answer.

Comment: @Anupam : yes just declare activity in testProject's manifest file which you want to call from library project

Answer (score 0):

agree with @Karakuri aplly his advice and this code
try the following code

```
nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(SearchBar.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Now getting `NullPointerException` at the same place. 
`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException`.
I have done like this: `Context context;`, `context = SearchBar.this;`, `nm = (NotificationManager) context
    .getSystemService(SearchBar.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);`

Comment: Here you can use `nm = (NotificationManager) SearchBar.this.getSystemService(SearchBar.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);`

Comment: Again the same error `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()` at the same `getSystemService`.

Comment: yes becuase searchBar should not be an activity. apply @Karakuri answer. and then use my line

Answer (score 0):

Activities are not meant to be instantiated yourself via the `new` keyword. The Android OS is supposed to do that. Here's what I would change:

1. Don't have SearchBar extend `Activity`.
2. Give SearchBar a `public` method (could even be a `static` method) that takes a `Context` as a parameter. Use that to obtain the `NotificationManager` instance.

Like so

```
public class SearchBar {
    private SearchBar() {/* no instantiation */}

    public static void notifyPersistently(Context context) {
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(SearchBar.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // all the rest ...
    }
}
```